# Passing larger sized char array as compared to the size of char array in function parameter in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a below C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test(char a[2])
{
    printf("%s", a);
}
int main()
{
    char t[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    test(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `abcd`

In the above code, I am passing a char pointer (char array of sized 5 bytes). But the function has parameter sized 2 bytes (`char a[2]`). The program works fine.

Why there is no compilation error or warnings? Does it not mean this line `void test(char a[2])` is expecting 2 bytes of array?

I had a debate over this with my colleague. Please enlightened me in this case.

Answer (score 4):

> Why there is no compilation error or warnings? Does it not mean this
>   line void test(char a[2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3)) is expecting 2 bytes of array?

Unless it's preceded by `static`, the `2` in `void test(char a[2]);` is, (for backward compatibility reasons that trace all the way back to the [`B` language (C's predecessor)](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html)) only as good as a comment.

In other words,

```
void test(char a[2]);
void test(char a[2017]);
void test(char a[]);
void test(char *a);
```

are all completely equivalent declarations.

The newly (C11) allowed:

```
void test(char a[static 2]);
```

syntax allows the author of `test` to say it really must get a pointer to an array that has *at least* 2 items (more is fine), and [C11 makes it undefined](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3) for the caller of `test` to call it with anything that doesn't satisfy this requirement. However, you can't count on a warning.

Practically, out of gcc/clang, only clang warns and only sometimes (and tinycc doesn't even support this extended syntax)

```
void test(char a[static 2]);
int main()
{
    char a[1]={0}, b=0;
    test(a); //clang warns about array bounds (gcc doesn't)
    test(&(char){'a'}); //no warning
    test(&b); //no warning
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Compiler ignore the size of first dimension of array in function parameter. Prototype

```
void test(char a[2]);
```

is equivalent to

```
void test(char a[]);   
void test(char *a);
```

or you can say compiler just interpret `void test(char a[2]);` as `void test(char *a)`.
Similarly

```
void void test2(char a[5][5]);
```

is equivalent to

```
  void void test2(char a[][5]);   
  void void test2(char (*a)[5]);
```

Comment: So, what is preferred to be written:`void test(char a[2])` or `void test(char *a)` or `void test(char a[])`?

Comment: It's up to a programer to choose between three. I would prefer `void test(char *a)`.

Comment: @PankajKumarThapa `char a[]` has been conventionally used to mean "I'm expecting  an array" as opposed  to just a pointer to a single object, but it doesn't really matter which form you use.

Answer (score 1):

No. It decays into `char*`. And you `print` a `\0` terminated char array by providing the address.

Array decays into pointer to the first element. And here the first element is a `char` so it decays into `char*` containing the address of the first element.

And also when you pass an array the first dimension is ignored by the compiler.

#### Why didn't the compiler complain?

So the main thing is **it is not possible to pass an array in C**. If you pass one then basically pointer to the first element is passed. And as there is no size of array needed here, the `2` is ignored here. That's why compiler didn't complain.

#### Does it not mean this line `void test(char a[2])` is expecting 2 bytes of array?

No. it doesn't. That's why you can even do this `void test(char a[])` or this `void test(char a[2017])`.

Answer (score 1):

An array as a function parameter is automatically converted to a pointer.  So this:

```
void test(char a[2])
```

Is identical to this:

```
void test(char *a)
```

This works because an array decays to a pointer in most contexts, including as a parameter to a function.

Answer (score 1):

When pass array as a function arguments,it decay immediately into pointers, an array is never actually passed to a function. So, you getting size of pointer instead of array.

C11 6.3.2.1/3:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue.